# ValueError: iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Пытаюсь заполнить значениями колонку датафрейма и выбивает ошибку. Помогите исправить

```
for coord in all_coords:
    for spec in all_spec:
        result_df[str(coord) + str(spec)]=0

result_df.head()



def get_full_proba(i):
    print(i)
    counter = 1
    for coord_idx, coord in enumerate(all_coords):
        for spec_idx, spec in enumerate(all_spec):
            coords_proba = spec_proba_by_coords_df.iat[i, coord_idx+3]
            spec_proba = spec_proba_df.iat[i, spec_idx+3]
            result_df.iat[i, counter]=float(coords_proba)*float(spec_proba)
            counter += 1


result_df.copy()[0:1].swifter.apply(lambda row: get_full_proba(row), axis=1)
```

```
ValueError: iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а что у вас в `row` и соответственно в `i`? Что печатает `print(i)`? Ошибка говорит, что `.iat` работает только с целыми числами.

Comment: i=row, в каждую строчку добавляется значение произведения

Comment: Как время будет посмотрю. Но там немало кода, это надо время разбираться. Так то и мне полезно будет, про `swifter` я не знал, например :)

Comment: Хорошо, в двух словах. Я пытаюсь создать таблицу по общему кластеру и contractors, заполняя её произведением вероятностей по двум кластерам. Я не понимаю, какие числовые значения нужны. Я же итак заполняю числами.

Comment: Ну я подозреваю, что row это Series, а не число, но это нужно смотреть